# Gradle war plugin creation of directory structure

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Using Eclipse I created a Gradle application which is a library, I want to create a web application and generate a `.war` file, so I added the `war` plugin:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
    id 'war'
}
```

On the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html it says that it creates a directory structure, but it doesn't create for me. Do I have to do something for it to create it or do I have to create it by hand?